# How to leave the Bitcoin testnet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet

My [BitcoinCore client](https://bitcoin.org/en/download) says it's on the testnet. I've done nothing to configure this. How do I change it to do real Bitcoin transactions and wallets?

Also, every time I shutdown my PC the client had to rebuild the entire Bitcoin transaction history. Is that because it's on the testnet? It seems unworkable to me if I have to do an entire rebuild every time I want to shutdown my PC or install an update.

I haven't been able to find any information on the purpose of the testnet and the differences between the main Bitcoin network. Although I can make guesses.

Comment: Is this on Windows and using GUI? What do you see in `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf` ?

Comment: @Prayank Bitcoin doesn't have a folder in AppData, while lots of other programs do. I also looked in other AppData folders. While searching for this file I found that 2 clients have been installed. 1 testclient (green) and 1 real Bitcoin client (orange). Having started the real one it's almost finished updating the transaction record :) I also have access to the wallet I created. Apparently the first time I got the right client, but later the OS found me the testclient, so it never downloaded the same transaction history again.

Comment: Great. Yes on windows when you search for "bitcoin core" you will see two options: Green (Testnet) and Orange (Mainnet)